# How to implement the android zoomview?

Tags: android, zooming

I want to implement the android-zoom-view (https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/).
I added the jar to the buildpath. I created the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pl.polidea.view.ZoomView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/webcam1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/webcam2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />
</pl.polidea.view.ZoomView>
```

and added the following code to my activity:

```
    View v = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.zoomable_view, null, false);
    v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
    zoomView.addView(v);

    LinearLayout main_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    main_container.addView(zoomView);
```

what am I doing wrong?
I get the following error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class pl.polidea.view.ZoomView
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the following constructor to the ZoomView class and it works now at least for one imageview in the zoomview.

```
public ZoomView(final Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
     super(context, attr);     
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding the jar file to build path doesn't work.
You have to go to "Order and Export Tab" and check on the jar file to be included in classpath.
(Order and Export Tab is available in the Properties menu of project.)

Comment: Thank you. I now enabled the jar file in the "order and export tab". But the problem still remains.

Comment: Xml suppoert for zoomview is still to come.
Kindly refer this: https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/issues/detail?id=2